# Linux find WiFi Networks protocol (a/b/g/n) version of all available access points

Tags: linux, wifi, openwrt

I do use `iwlist wlan0 scanning` and it gives me a fair amount of data, but one part is missing: It is the protocol version. By protocol I mean (a/b/g/n).

It would be very good to have these commands in a standard distro. I am using OpenWRT.

Comment: See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191650/how-to-know-which-standard-my-wi-fi-connection-is-currently-using): "How to know which standard my Wi-Fi connection is currently using"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`iwconfig` (and its wireless extension API) is deprecated (it's in "maintenance only mode" and "no new features will be added").

Use [`iw`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/iw.8) instead. This requires a moderately recent kernel (e.g. >= 3.0) with support for `nl80211`.

Using `iw dev wlan0 scan`, you can figure out the protocol used:

- If there are `Supported rates` below 11 Mbps (except 6), there might be `802.11b` support (even APs which allow disabling b support will announce those rates but reject b-only clients).
- If there are `Supported rates` or `Extended supported rates` above 11 Mbps or 6 Mbps, there might be `802.11g` support (even APs which are set to require_mode n will announce those rates but reject b/g clients).
- If there are `HT capabilities`, there is some kind of `802.11n` support. The specific high throughput features available are dependent on whether there is a secondary channel (in that case you are using a 40 MHz channel, so you have 150 Mbps per special stream instead of 72.2 Mbps), and the number of special streams supported for TX and RX.
- If you are on the bleeding edge and you see a `VHT`, welcome to the `802.11ac` world.

Comment: Isn't there any tool in 2023 out there which directly reports the available standards (a/b/g/n/ac/ax) of the available networks?

Comment: @student, using wpa_supplicant's `wpa_cli status` you get info including wifi_generation (that you're currently using?) and ieee80211ac (support?), so maybe it can do it.

Comment: @hkBst you might want to make that a full answer rather than just a comment? Seems like a good alt answer to the question and general problem

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs, thanks, I did as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Using wpa_supplicant's `wpa_cli status` you get the following output, which includes wifi_generation (that you're currently using?) and ieee80211ac (support?):

```
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid=77:77:11:88:aa:dd
freq=5240
ssid=XXX
id=10
mode=station
wifi_generation=5
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=CCMP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=192.168.1.25
address=44:77:aa:dd:55:65
ieee80211ac=1
```