# How to tell what wireless protocols my network card is using?

Tags: networking, wifi, networkcard, protocols

I want to know which wireless protocol my card is currently using. I found a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62265/linux-find-wifi-networks-trotocola-b-g-n-version-of-all-available-access-point) that tells you what network protocol your card supports, but I want to confirm that my card is actually using that protocol with a given AP.

In Windows and Mac you can see this information by simply hovering over the connection; see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/381963/how-to-tell-if-my-wi-fi-is-connecting-using-802-11n) and [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7956/how-can-i-know-which-wi-fi-protocol-my-macbook-is-using). How can I do this in Linux?

Comment: I actually just found out that I can inspect the ethernet packets in Wireshark and check the "Channel type" field in the Radiotap Header. However, I'd like to know an easier way to do it.

Comment: Actually, the value in "Channel type" doesn't match what Windows reports the protocol is, so I'm not sure if that's accurate.

Answer (score 1):

As you already figured out different 802.11 flavors (a/b/g/n) are capable of different data rates.
802.11g has a max. of 54 Mb/s, so if you see your wireless driver using a data rate higher than 54 Mb/s it's probably using 802.11n.

GUI:
For example with Network Manager there is an item called 'Information' which has an entry 'Speed'.
CMD:
`iwconfig wlan0` has an entry Bit Rate

Or you can inspect the TX/RX frames, like you said in your comment, to see with which data rate they were sent/received.

Comment: I thought about this, but the bit rate is often a strange number. For example, right now for me it is 58 Mbps, and occasionally it goes up to 65 Mbps. Sometimes I've seen it drop down to 1 Mbps (but my internet wasn't slow at all). I wasn't sure if I should trust this number to determine the protocol.

Comment: Where did you get these numbers? Since you also mentioned 1 Mbps, I assume you're looking at a (Wireshark) trace that shows you the data rate per frame. You simply cannot link these to what you experience as a user.